# Is there an equivalent in Java to .NET's FlexGrid control?

Tags: java

Is there an equivalent in Java to .NET's FlexGrid control?

Comment: What's the result of your investigation?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the GridBagLayout.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

Comment: Thanks for your response.But I need to know can I connect that grid to database like Sql server.

Comment: Then you need to expand your question to explain what you are actually trying to do and where you are having problems.